# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Priority Deployment

Tags: azure-devops

I'm just wondering is there any settings for Azure DevOps that we can set priority for each deployment?

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see I have several deployment stages for each project. We usually develop on first one which put in red square on screenshot.

Azure DevOps randomly pick one of the project and deploy it to the machine.

What I want is to set some kind of priority for each stages. Hey you should deploy first, then you should second and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your release pipeline as one after another like below.

Here I just define **2 stages** like `Dev` and `QA`

Once the deployment is completed in `DEV` then it will start the deployment to the `QA` and so on

[image]

You can also change this by using the `pre-deployment conditions`

[image]

As I mentioned in the comment,  I'm not about like a priority wise, one workaround is like you can use the `manual intervention`

From the below pipeline, let say `DEV 2` and `QA` having low priority which means I want to first deploy the DEV (1st priority)

[image]

Dev 2

[image]

QA

[image]

In this way the Dev 2 and QA the manual intervention step will be holding the further task, the people will get the email. Once the email is approved the task will resume to the further steps.

Again this is not exactly you want, but giving the possible ways to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Hello Jayendran, thanks for your answer. We actually use this kind of scenario for our Azure and On-Premise deployment for production. https://imgur.com/a/URX2B7C I just wanted to know is there any way to set the priority under this circumstances. It's too hard to change the whole pipeline everytime when you want to deploy one project first, and then the rest :( But I upvoted your answer anyway. Thanks

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral I'm not sure any such thing like a priority, but I'd recommend to look out for [manual-intervention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=vsts), you can define this task in your QA envir as a first step.During the process, while execution it will send a mail to the concerned person once they approved the process will move further.

Comment: I will have a look. Cheers mate!

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral let me know if that helps

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral your converted way is similar to my answer. But you really want a solution for your pipeline in your question right? You can include the `manual intervention` task as the initial task in the environment(s) which you prefer the least priority, that task let you approve the further process in your environments

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand what do you mean. Can you explain on another answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your stage and then to the right there is a box with a delete button.  To the right of that delete button is a MOVE button.  That will allow you to order the stages.

Comment: That;s already in place. Whatever I want to deploy first is on the top of the stages. Please have a look again to the screenshot on my question again. The third stage is already deployed and first one is deploying on that screenshot. Even if it is sorted like this, azure devops randomly picks the stages. So I converted to like this. https://imgur.com/a/pYIz4CF

Comment: Interesting.  I'll keep an eye on mine.  It could be possible you were experiencing a bug that has been fixed.  Maybe moving them around and then back into order would fix it.